# sonarqube embedded javascript in xml support?

Tags: javascript, xml, sonarqube, cdata

we're looking at using sonarqube for code inspections for our application that is run inside an internal tool and all javascript code is embedded in xml files as below within the CDATA block. What's the best way of allowing sonarqube to properly inspect the embedded javascript code? Just extract the javascript code and then run sonarqube on that extracted code - we tried that and it works but we wouldn't get the parameters verified etc...

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<script name="test.test2.test3.testFunction">
   <label>testFunction</label>
   <metaVersion>25</metaVersion>
   <parameterList>
    <parameter name="par1" type="rifp"/>
    <parameter name="par2" type="rifp"/>
  </parameterList>
  <script><![CDATA[
    if(par1==par2){
        return true;
    }
  ]]></script>
</script>
```

Regards,
Mikael

Answer (score 0):

There's currently an open github issue for SonarJS that should partially cover your needs when implemented : https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-javascript/issues/581

It will not in any way interpret your wrapping xml though, only analyse the javascript within the file. It will give you similar results to what you are getting now by extracting the js from the xml and running the analysis, except that it will happen transparently.